# .NET 5 Core Web Application with Docker Compose gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, .net-5

I'm trying to run a .NET 5 web application in a Docker container locally with Docker Desktop. Nothing fancy, it's just a new ASP.NET Core Web Application created with Visual Studio 2019.
Starting the web application from Visual Studio works, it loads the /swagger/index.html page in the browser.

Then I added Container Support in Visual Studio with Docker Compose.
When I start that, it fails to load in the browser. The error in the browser is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. The container is still running at this point. The container logs don't show any errors.

This is what the Docker file of the web app looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj", "WebApplication2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication2/WebApplication2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication2"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication2.dll"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  webapplication2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapplication2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication2/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:3000
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

Docker container logs show:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://[::]:3000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: /app
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://[::]:3000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: /app
```

I inspected the container. The ports config and the entry point:

```
"Ports": {
  "80/tcp": [
  {
    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
    "HostPort": "3000"
  }
  ]
}

"Entrypoint": [
  "tail",
  "-f",
  "/dev/null"
]
```

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Can you see any errors?

Comment: No, the 'docker container logs <containerid>' show all I posted above. Microsoft Edge shows: 
'Hmmm… can't reach this page
localhost took too long to respond'
Same in Chrome btw.

Comment: I've also tried this command: docker run --rm -it -d -p 8080:80 -p 8001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="abc" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=\https\aspnetapp.pfx -v ${PWD}\.aspnet\https:C:\https\ web-app:v1

but then it says "docker run" requires at least 1 argument, but I'm specifying the image at the end? This command come from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0